# replacing the dot character in the password field, Jframe, Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, character, jpasswordfield

I want to ask how can i change the character in the password field that was the point I want to replace with a star ???

i'm using Jframe, Java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PasswordTextField.setEchoChar('*');](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#setEchoChar%28char%29)