# How to remove default asterisks?

Tags: java, swing

In Netbeans a I have placed JpasswordField in the panel, can you advise me on how to remove default asterisks that appear in JpasswordField?

Comment: setEchoChar ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replacing the dot character in the password field, Jframe, Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390247/replacing-the-dot-character-in-the-password-field-jframe-java)

Comment: Why? The user needs a visible cue on how many characters of the password have been entered.

Comment: during development before I enter password I have to remove asterisks. Also even if the password consists of only 3 letters there too many asterisks, aprox. 15.

Answer (score 0):

To remove or change default character that appears instead of letters use [`JPasswordField#setEchoChar(char c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#setEchoChar(char)) method:

Example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Box rowOne = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    rowOne.add(new JLabel("Username"));
    rowOne.add(new JTextField());

    Box rowTwo = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    rowTwo.add(new JLabel("Password"));
    JPasswordField jpassword = new JPasswordField();

    rowTwo.add(jpassword);
    f.add(rowOne, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    f.add(rowTwo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    f.setSize(300, 200);
    f.setVisible(true);

    jpassword.setEchoChar('#');

    System.out.println(jpassword.getEchoChar());

  }
}
```